# WP7 constraints on image width/height on gestureListener

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am following this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/gg650664%28en-us%29.aspx) to learn how to pinch, drag and rotate an image in windows phone 7. But I have noticed that the image can be dragged, zoomed out off the screen.

Is there any way to constrains on image width/height?

Comment: I mean any way to stop the image being dragged off the screen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to implement constrains on your own. Basically you always have a container element that contains the image and I assume this container has a width/height set.

Both container and image have 4 points in space (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right). For constraints you just need to check that none of those points for the image do not go over container ones.

To calculate top-left point use:

```
var transform = image.TransformToVisual(container);         
Point topLeftPoint = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

To calculate top-right point just add Image.Width to topLeftPoint.X. To calculate bottom-left point add Image.Height to topLeftPoint.Y. To calculate bottom-right point add both Image.Height to topLeftPoint.Y and Image.Width to topLeftPoint.X.

Then you just need to check for ContainerTopLeftPoint.X >= ImageTopLeftPoint.X and ContainerTopLeftPoint.Y >= ImageTopLeftPoint.Y... similar check for every point (but keep in mind that for bottom points it should be <= instead of >= ).

Pure math :)